# How to view packages imported in the java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javadoc, eclipse-che

I'm a student and newbie in java coding. Currently, I'm analyzing codes

from `eclipse/che` for `ide` and editor customizing.

There are packages such as import `org.eclipse.che.api.core`

I wanna look into `org.eclipse.che.api.core` , and I couldn't find a way to

do so. (Also no `javadoc` found)

Any advice for this problem?

Comment: open a browser and search for `org.eclipse.che.api.core source code`

Comment: I could have downloaded code from https://github.com/eclipse/che in eclipse and generated javadocs for this code to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse and build your project with Maven, you usually can jump into the source code of any class with F3 (on the class name in your code) - if the class is from an external jar, Eclipse downloads the source code (if available) and opens it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have external libraries folder in the project explorer. Expand it and you should find what you are looking for.